# With Micropython on an ESP32 dev kit, what is the maximum time for deepsleep(time), where time is in millisecs?

Tags: time, sleep, esp32, micropython

I want to find out the maximum time that my ESP32 can Deep Sleep using Micropython **deepsleep(time)**), where time is in milliseconds.  I have tested from 10 seconds up to 24 hours so far, with satisfactory wakeup, but progress gets slower and slower the longer the sleep time.  I cannot find an answer on the web anywhere, except some say 71 minutes (wrong), so I hope someone knows the right answer.  In the meantime, I will extend the sleep time to 4 days and await results.

By the way, 24 hours in milliseconds is 86,400,000.

I am using this board:

JZK ESP-32S ESP32 Development Board 2.4GHz WiFi + Bluetooth Dual Mode Antenna Module with Ultra Low Power

https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B071JR9WS9/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1

with Espressif ESP32 WROOM 32D.

Answer (score 0):

you can sleep your ESP32 for as long as you want, but thats if you don'
t have a power outage or anything that may disrupt your program. its not about how long can it go its about how long it can last.

Comment: The result of the Four Day Test was OK - the ESP32 woke up and emailed me.  I have now set it to 8 days.  This is the setting I was using originally, which did not wake up.  This might have been a software error possibly, so I will wait a week and see.  I am surprised that no one seems to know the answer though.